# Measured Polarization for a Single Photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, polarization

I understand that for a given beam of light, it can exist in any number of polarizations. However, I have been told that given a single photon, it can only exist as horizontally or vertically polarized once measured. Is this correct, or can a single photon, just like any be measured at one of any number of polarizations?

Comment: Whoever told you that, stop listening to them. Unless they also added the caveat that you are free to choose the directions "horizontal" and "vertical" to point in whichever way you want.

Comment: A quantum system can exist in any superposition of states, so the answer to your question is negative.